# ASP.Net Core MVC Login user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC project I am working on, and I simply would like my user to login, and once logged in be brought to the userhome page.

I have created the model, the controller, and the view. In the View, I am not sure how to pass the full user into my controller because I have a [Bind] User in my method. To pass in a individual property I would use Model.Id, I'm assuming I need Model for the full object?

I am completely new with ASP.Net MVC. If you have any questions, please let me know.

```
// UserDataAccess login method with username or email, not sure if this is the correct way
public string ValidateLogin(User user)
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spUserLogin", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", user.Username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginEmail", user.Email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginPassword", user.Password);

        conn.Open();
        string result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        conn.Close();

        return result;
}
```

```
// LoginController 
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult UserLogin()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin([Bind] User user)
{
    //ModelState.Remove("Name");// ??

    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string loginStatus = objUser.ValidateLogin(user);

        if(loginStatus == "Success")
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, user.Id.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username, ClaimValueTypes.String),                        
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email, ClaimValueTypes.String),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.Name, ClaimValueTypes.String)
            };

            //ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "login");
            ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

            return RedirectToAction("UserHome", "User");
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["UserLoginFailed"] = "Login Failed. Plz enter correct data!";
            return View();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}

[Authorize]
public IActionResult UserHome()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
    return RedirectToAction("Login", "UserLogin");
}
```

```
// Login View
@model MVC_Login.Models.User
@*<form asp-action="UserLogin">*@

<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("UserLogin", "Login", new { Model })">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Username" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Username" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" />
        @*<a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn">Sign Up</a>*@
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you using Identity on ASP.NET Core? Take a look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Share us your current project and detail steps to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send a object model to a view using `return RedirectToAction("UserHome", "User")`. Also, you can send object (in your case with user data) to the "View" from Controller.;

First get user information and later use:

```
var userDataModel = foo; // Get user information
return View("ActionName", "ControllerName", userDataModel); // send to view
```

> **Note**: userDataModel object must be equal to model in view.

I hope can useful it.

Comment: This is the tutorial I have been going off of and I have basically everything the same as them but when i click Login btn with my user info in my txt boxes the page just sits there.

Comment: https://ankitsharmablogs.com/cookie-authentication-with-asp-net-core-2-0/

Comment: I downloaded project from Github and register my user without problems. You should make sure that you are clone project from Github [here](https://github.com/AnkitSharma-007/ASPCore.CookieAuth), create database and tables/store procedures. Remember change string conection appSettings.json. However, I have to say that Asp.Net Core have built in authentication with Identity Framework, youd don't need code it, just change authentication option when you are create project.